# Angular NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk

I'm new to angular and run into a problem. Everything runs fine but the error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" appears.

I've implemented a custom CdkStepper. On a specific cdk-step I use a [completed] directive.

In this step I have a component which has a list:

```
class ListComponent {
    list: ListElement[];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.listService.loadList().subscribe(l => this.list = l);
    }
}
```

Now the completed state depends whether the list is empty or not:

```
<my-stepper>
    <cdk-step [completed]="listComponent.list.length > 0">
        <list #listComponent></list>
    </cdk-step>
</my-stepper>
```

As I run the program the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` appears but everything works fine. Should I detect changes manually in `ngAfterViewInit()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things with the above code that should be changed. My guess is that you are receiving this error due to this line `this.list = this.listService.loadList().subscribe(l => this.list = l);`. It assigns to the list property twice. If the service call is returning quickly, then that should cause your error.

This line is incorrect though and should at a minimum be updated to `this.listService.loadList().subscribe(l => this.list = l);`. Typescript shouldn't even allow what you have because you are assigning a `Subscription` to what is supposed to be a `ListElement[]`. Just updating it as I've stated though might not be enough, because technically the list property will start off with the `undefined` value and if the service is returning quickly, the value of list will be updated to the results of the service call and will cause the same issue.

I would recommend using the `AsyncPipe`[docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). A few articles as to why this would be a better approach[1](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794), [2](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-async-pipe-angular).

What would this look like with your example?

```
class ListComponent {
    list$: Observble<ListElement[]> = this.listService.loadList();
}
```

```
<my-stepper *ngIf="list$ | async as list">
    <cdk-step [completed]="list.length > 0">
        <list #listComponent></list>
    </cdk-step>
</my-stepper>
```

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry, I made a typo when writing this post in the line where the service loads. I'm sorry, i'll update the question. In the original code everything is fine with this line. The line I have in the code is: this.listService.loadList().subscribe(l => this.list = l);

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I will checkout the AsyncPipe

Comment: The problem now is that I can not use the template variable listComponent.list$ in the *ngIf. It says that listComponent is not a know property. Is there a better work around than using template variables to get access of child component's list$?

Comment: It would help if you had an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). StackBlitz could help with this, but might be daunting to get started. In general, you don't access a child's properties. The parent component would be responsible for retrieving the list and passing it to the child. There are times where events occur on children and you want the parent to know about that. In such a case you can pass information to the parent via a separate service or through an Output property. Without context around what you are trying to accomplish, it is hard to advise.